# How to play a song from the internet using python

Tags: python, stream, pyqt, streaming, phonon

I am trying to use PyQt4 and Phonon (on windows 8 64 bits) to play a song from the internet (streaming, ex: http://dr5huvbk6x9di.cloudfront.net/cloudfront_songs/file4.ogg)

To play a song from the filesystem is working, but when I try to play from the internet it doesn't. I read the documentation and it seems everything is fine. The error is a FatalError, so is hard to understand what is going on. Phonon can't play the song from the internet?

Another questions is that I read that phonon has been deprecated and we have PyQt5. So, which is the best way to do what I am trying to do.

Here is my code. It is a little bit messy because I just wanted to work, so I could understand and then make it better. Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, win_parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, win_parent)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Widgets
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("ply music player")
        self.fs_button = QtGui.QPushButton("FileSystem", self)
        self.ws_button = QtGui.QPushButton("WebStream", self)

        # Phonon actions
        self.mediaObject = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.audioOutput = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.MusicCategory, self)
        Phonon.createPath(self.mediaObject, self.audioOutput)

        # Connect signal
        self.fs_button.clicked.connect(self.on_fs_clicked)
        self.mediaObject.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)      
        self.ws_button.clicked.connect(self.on_ws_clicked)

        # Vertical layout (manages the layout automatically)
        v_box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.fs_button)
        v_box.addWidget(self.ws_button)

        # Create central widget, add layout and set
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def on_fs_clicked(self):
        if self.mediaObject.state() == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.mediaObject.stop()
        else:
            files = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, self.fs_button.text())
            if files:
                songs = []
                for file in files:
                    songs.append(Phonon.MediaSource(file))
                self.mediaObject.setQueue(songs)
                self.mediaObject.play()
                self.fs_button.setText("FileSystem")

    def handleStateChanged(self, newstate, oldstate):
        if newstate == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.fs_button.setText("Stop")
        elif newstate == Phonon.StoppedState:
            self.fs_button.setText("FileSystem")
        elif newstate == Phonon.ErrorState:
            source = self.mediaObject.currentSource().fileName()
            print "ERROR: ", self.mediaObject.errorType()
            print "ERROR: could not play:", source.toLocal8Bit().data()


    def on_ws_clicked(self):
        if self.mediaObject.state() == Phonon.PlayingState:
            self.mediaObject.stop()
        else:
            song = "http://dr5huvbk6x9di.cloudfront.net/cloudfront_songs/file4.ogg"
            self.mediaObject.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(song))
            print self.mediaObject.currentSource()
            self.mediaObject.play()
            self.ws_button.setText("WebStream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ply = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ply.setApplicationName("Ply")
    ply.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(ply.exec_())
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me on Linux and WinXP when streaming audio. Looks like it could be an issue with your specific setup.

Comment: A friend of mine tried on Linux and didn't work. What do you mean with specific setup? Your OS is 32 or 64 bits? Which Linux distro did you use? Thank you for the feedback.. I was getting frustrated.

Comment: By "didn't work", you mean your friend got the _exact same error_, or what exactly? Specific setup means the versions of PyQt, Qt etc you are using, but could also include your network configuration. (PS: I tested on Arch Linux).

Comment: Well, he didn't have support for playing mp3. In other words, his backend needed some adjustment. Now it is working on his linux. I checked the phonon doc and Windows need directx 9 or higher (I have 11) and the Windows SDK (which I am downloading now). Do you have it installed? It is weird cause the local mp3 they play normally. If this is the problem, nothing should work. I guess.

Comment: I don't have the Win SDK installed, but I did have to install the [K-Lite codec pack](http://codecguide.com/about_kl.htm) to resolve some media-related issues once - can't remember exactly what for, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was installing codecs to play .ogg files. Thanks to @ekhumoro.